# Android Phone-to-Phone Communications

Tags: android

This is more about an explanation then it is about asking a question. What I am wondering is if its possible to write an Android application that can communicate with another Android phone, given the phone number of the phone I want to communicate with. By communicate, I mean I want to be able to send data to the phone and have my application on the other phone be able to recive it.

If its not possible to do this, then I guess my alternative is to have my application "sign" the phone into a server. Then I'm assuming the server can act a proxy to communicate with both phones.

Any clarification would be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [BUMP](http://bu.mp/) api. It allows you to establish a connection between two (I think more are also possible) devices, and it gives you a channel over which to communicate. The devices need to be "bumped" first, but then it's all fair game.

Comment: `BUMP` is no longer available

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why it has to be by phone number? That and i'm pretty sure you can only send data over WAN or local bluetooth/wifi.

Perhaps try something along the lines of a server that has phones sign into it and keeps track of the phones IP addresses allowing them to communicate almost directly to another (kind of like a dynamic DNS hah!).

Comment: I only wanted to do it by phone number because phone numbers are unique. The user could simply select a contact from their contacts list and I could use the phone number to identify the phone I need to send the data to

Answer (score 0):

Look into SMS. I haven't coded for mobile phones in years but I seem to recall that most phone operating systems let an app intercept SMS messages, react to their contents, and prevent the user from seeing them.

As long as you're not sending lots of data, SMS might do the trick.